# Django Circular Model Dependency

Tags: python, database, django, database-design, django-models

I have a circular dependency in my Django models, such that model A has a foreign key reference to B, while B has a many-to-many reference to A. I've consulted other SO posts and have used the string model names instead of the actual classes, but to no avail. Here are abbreviated versions of my two classes:

**User model**

```
import listings.models

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField('listings.models.Listing')
```

**Listing model**

```
import users.models

class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.models.User')
```

Every time I attempt to run **syncdb**, it outputs the following error:

> Error: One or more models did not validate: users.user: 'favorites'
>   has an m2m relation with model listings.models.Listing, which has
>   either not been installed or is abstract. listings.listing: 'owner'
>   has a relation with model users.models.User, which has  either not
>   been installed or is abstract.

How do I resolve this without sacrificing the established relationship?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `'listings.models.Listing'` should be `'listings.Listing'`
- `'users.models.User'` should be `'users.User'` (or `'auth.User'` if you were to use `django.contrib.auth.models.User`)

Refer to [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for more.

Comment: `listings.Listing` and `users.User`, respectively. Case is still important.

Comment: Thanks, answer updated to match the documentation ... but I'm puzzled because it [works without the case too](https://github.com/jpic/django_test/blob/366d2474dab1774be5b7fbb49354d38eb7e5e741/test_app/models.py) on Django 1.4.2. Maybe it's a bug ?

Comment: Wow, thanks, that worked. Is that specific to Django, or does Python normally allow you to dereference a class via a package rather than its parent module?

Comment: It's django-specific. But you can use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete your imports because, you're not depend on them on code. You use just string with model name - it's not a dependency.
Also you should delete `models` - from your strings because you can refer to your model as `app_name.model_name`